# Global Portal Web Rules and Accessibility Rules?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, standards

A design agency I work for recently contacted me regarding the website development of one of their major (corporate) clients. They said:

> The HTML must be done according to the
>   many global portal web rules and
>   accessibility rules.

... although they'll provide more information on "global portal" and "accessibility" rules sometime later but I wanted to know about them in advance to not sound dumb. Does anyone know what they're and where can I read more about them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read about accessibility on [w3c](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility) site. No idea what *global portal web rules* means.